# Android WebView accessibility in Lollipop

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I'm having some trouble getting TalkBack to work with a web view (testing with a Nexus 9 on Android 5.1). I read that TalkBack support was added to web views around the release of Android JellyBean by checking a preference titled "Enhance Web Accessibility." I can't for the life of me find this preference in the system settings.

Focusing on the web view in our application simply reads "WebView" and provides no other options.

Was TalkBack support for web views removed in KitKat? If not, what am I missing here?

Am using Mobile accessibility Plugin to read my customized talkback

My app work fine with Android 4.4.4 . Am using `aria-hidden=true` to stop default talkback of Mobile accessibility. But with that attribute lollipop doesn't  focus to the event and not all reading

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little unclear.  But I can guarantee one thing, this has nothing to do with the "Enhanced Web Accessibility" option.  This was an experimental accessibility setting in Android 4.1 - 4.2 and has since been deprecated.  This is why you cannot find this setting.  What "Enhanced Web Accessibility" did was add some visual elements to help users spot things like Links and such with nice outlines.  It has nothing to do with basic TalkBack support for WebViews, which has been supported since TalkBack was released, though it has certainly improved since then, and is still improving.

Now, this doesn't really answer your question.  Only removes one of the solutions you seem to have been concerned about investigating.  As per your actual solution, your question is a little unclear what your actual problem is.  It seems to me you have some sort of event firing in a custom WebView you have created, and this should cause TalkBack to read something out.  I await further details to continue this answer, though I suspect that you have not set the WebView's accessibility delegate.

```
mWebView.setAccessibilityDelegate(new View.AccessibilityDelegate());
```

Comment: We are using phonegap 3.6 to develop app with html5 file ,it  works fine in kit kat but not in lollipop

Answer (score -1):

It must be set to setJavaScriptEnabled (false);
web components analysis appears to be view.view.

Comment: My job is completely using Javascript if am doing what you have mentioned nothing is loading